# Can't execute simple python script on localhost

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I am trying to execute simple python script on my localhost.

Script is placed at htdocs-> test.py

Script is :

```
#!C:\Users\First Last\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python\python.exe
print("Single Quotes")
```

Before hitting http:\localhost\test.py in browser, I started apache server. Also added below lines at the end of file : httpd.conf:

AddHandler cgi-script .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict

But still when i hit http:\localhost\test.py in browser, it shows error that:

```
Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.7
```

I read many articles /posts on the internet to resolve this but still can't resolve it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to output HTTP response headers as well.

For example:

```
#!C:\Users\First Last\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python\python.exe
print("Content-type: text/plain\n")
print("Single Quotes")
```